# How can I permanently enable in a firewall ruby packed in exe by ocra?

Tags: ruby, firewall

I wrote an utility, that sends messages over internet and packed it in an exe file with ocra.
Each time I run that exe firewall asks me whether it should block or enable that exe.

It happens because when the exe starts it unpacks ruby.exe each time to different tmp directory, thus the firewall percieves ruby as an unknown program.

How can I manage ocra to use the same tmp path to which it extracts ruby? Is there a ruby way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're talking about windows firewall?

Comment: Yes, about windows builtin one

Comment: couldn't you just use a specific port and open the firewall port regardless of the application using it?

Comment: At the risk of sounding simplistic, why don't you just unpack the EXE to the same temporary directory?

Comment: Opening the port had no effect - popups still appeared.

Unpacking EXE to random directory ocra does, not me. I asked for a way to direct ocra to the permanent specific directory.

Inno Setup rulez )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using innosetup with ocra to make a windows installer.

Comment: Thank you! That was it!
I tried ocra with Inno Setup - it is cool.